# Delete entire rows based on a value contained in the row with macro?

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have a spreadsheet which contains a whole bunch of text and number values.  I would like to have a macro search the sheet, select the rows containing the word "Total" and delete the entire row.  I have been searching for hours and have not found any code that I can adapt to perform this task.  I have a little experience with VBA but am out of practice and patience.  The word is not case sensitive and may be contained in a string of text, for example: "Total for 12345 Jane Doe".

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead:

```
Sub testing()
Dim pattern As String
pattern = "Total"
RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To RowCount
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To 1
        If Cells(i, j) = pattern Then
           Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

This may have more lines of code,but this will be helpful to explain your concept.

To insert it do the following in excel:

1. press Alt+F11
2. Rightclick Sheet1
3. ->Insert->Module and paste this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the entire range, the following macro should delete every row that has a cell that contains "total", regardless of case.

```
Sub Test()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection
    If InStr(1, cell, "total", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

To insert it, do the following in Excel:

1. Press Alt+F11
2. Click Insert>Module
3. Copy and paste the above macro into the new module.

Comment: I really want to use this but it goes in an endless loop...